# Plotting multiple columns groupedby on a single graph

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plot, group-by, seaborn

[image]

For the above Pandas DataFrame `pd` I want to plot according to the following conditions:

- A single line plot
- For each algorithm the x-axis = `num_ingress` and y-axis = `['total_flows', 'successful flows', 'dropped_flows']`. So for each algo there must be 3 lines on the plot
- The Labels for the y-axis have to be the algorithm name + the column, e.g. `A - Total Flows`, `B - Total Flows` etc

I have tried the `groupby` of `matplotlib` but then I get multiple groups and I only can plot one graph per group. Not all lines on a single plot. I also tried `seaborn` but couldn't make it work based on `groupby` aswell.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your dataframe, make sure to use [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) to sort by algorithm and num_ingress.

```
import pandas as pd

algorithm = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B']
num_ingress = [4, 2, 1, 3, 5, 4, 2, 1, 3, 5]
total_flow = [8000, 4000, 2000, 6000, 10000, 8000, 4000, 2000, 6000, 10000]
successful_flows = [5985, 3994, 1997, 5991, 1994, 5975, 3988, 1996, 5974, 5087]
dropped_flows = [2000, 0, 0, 0, 7991, 2005, 0, 0, 9, 4889]

df = pd.DataFrame({'algorithm': algorithm,
      'num_ingress': num_ingress,
      'total_flow': total_flow,
      'successful_flows': successful_flows,
      'dropped_flows': dropped_flows
     })

df.sort_values(['algorithm', 'num_ingress'], inplace=True)
df
```

then plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

for i, algorithm in enumerate(df.groupby('algorithm')):
    algorithm_df = pd.DataFrame(algorithm[1])
    plt.subplot(1, 2, i+1)
    plt.plot(algorithm_df['num_ingress'], algorithm_df[['total_flow', 'successful_flows', 'dropped_flows']])
    plt.title("Algorithm {}".format(algorithm_df['algorithm'].values[0]))

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]